# Where did the Auditore and Kenway lines merge?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

It's well known that [Flavia Auditore (1513 - Unknown)](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Flavia_Auditore) is a direct ancestor of [William Miles](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/William_Miles) (and therefore the Assassin's Creed present day protagonist Desmond Miles).

[image: Assassin's Creed Revelations: Abstergo Files]

We also know that [Edward Kenway](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Kenway) is [the first member of the Kenway line to be in the Assassins](http://www.nave360.com/assassins-creed-iv-black-flag-official-qa/):

> Edward will be thrown in the middle of the ancient war between Templars and Assassins. He will be trained by them and finally become the first Kenway member of the Assassin Order. He’s the father of Haytham, Connor is therefore Edward’s grandson.

In other words, Edward Kenway is known *not to be* a descendant of Flavia Auditore. Neither is [Ziio](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Kanieht%C3%AD:io), as a native American in the 18th century. **So when did the lines merge?**

One theory (mine) is that [Tessa Kenway](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Tessa_Kenway) is a descendant of the Auditore line, but I haven't read [Assassin's Creed: Forsaken](http://amzn.com/0425261514) and none of my research suggests that there's any evidence to support this. I can't find any earlier reference to William Miles life than this [story from 1977.](http://www.accesstheanimus.com/ACI_modern_times.html#28)

**Is it known *when and where* the Auditore and Kenway lines merge to create the *Miles* line?**

Comment: well, considering Ezio's character he might have a illegitimate child somewhere :-)....

Comment: @Stefto Nope, we know that it's Flavia

Comment: I found no answer to this but [this family line diagram](http://okiir.deviantart.com/art/Assassin-s-Creed-Desmond-Miles-Family-Tree-309154704) that is a little bit better to read than the provided one.

Comment: @Kovah the person who made that tree (which I agree, is better, though it is not canon, my posted one is canon as it was made by Ubisoft) explicitly says that the connections are not known. For what it's worth, the answer "it is not known / it has not been released by Ubisoft" is a valid answer to this question, though would require some citation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As somebody mentioned in a comment, and as I mentioned in a [previous answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/181837/how-are-desmonds-assassin-ancestors-related-to-each-other/181846#181846) to a very similar question, **it is currently unknown** how the Auditore and Kenway lines connect.

As you likely already know, both from your official diagram and from the comments, Desmond appears to be related to the [Kenways](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Kenway_family) and [Auditores](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/House_of_Auditore) through his father [William Miles](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/William_Miles).

As such, we can focus on the paternal lineage (barring any weird, incestuous connection among Desmond's paternal and maternal ancestors). Beginning with the Auditores, Ezio had two children we know of: [Flavia](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Flavia_Auditore) (as you referenced in your question) and [Marcello](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Marcello_Auditore). Although the line in the canonical diagram you posted above appears to be highlighted the lineage flowing through Flavia, in theory Marcello could also prove to be the link (though this is pure speculation, and would require future confirmation by Ubisoft). Nonetheless, both of these children represent the latest known canonical individuals in the Auditore line.

However, to elaborate on the information we do have, we know the earliest instances of the Kenway line are in the form of Edward's parents, [Bernard](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Bernard_Kenway#cite_note-Black_Flag_novel-1) and [Linette](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Linette_Kenway) (both from the [Black Flag book](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed:_Black_Flag)). As such, some link could potentially exist flowing from Flavia to Bernard and Linette.

As you mentioned in your question, the link existing through [Tessa](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Tessa_Kenway) is also possible: we do not know much about Tessa Kenway or her family tree (beyond her father being some sort of [wealthy landowner](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Tessa_Kenway)). Again, since there is a vacuum of information, Tessa being the link is entirely possible. However, based on the current information, the Auditore lineage would have to connect to either Bernard, Linette, or Tessa (and **not** [Caroline Scott](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Caroline_Scott-Kenway), as she is not directly related to [Haytham](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Haytham) and consequently the paternal lineage).

Unfortunately, with respect to the familial lineage, the sources we have are limited, with the diagram you posted being a significant step forward in the identification process. However, I can point you to [this extensive chart](http://ultimatezetya.deviantart.com/art/UPDATED-2017-Assassins-Creed-Ancestry-Family-Tree-602758002) which, though not canonical, is nevertheless a useful resource for yourself and others attempting to trace the familial lineages of the Miles family as it is understood today in May 2017.

Comment: Sadly, this is not much more information than I posted in my question, except to mention Edward Kenway's parents which I was not aware of as I have only played the main games and not read any books. However, since you seem to have more knowledge from sources not easily found googling, I'm going to take your word that it's actually not known (vs. me not being able to find it), and give you the check.

Comment: Yeah, its tough since there's really no new information.I tried to supplement the information provided in the question while also attempting to answer the question as best I could, again given the absence of information on the topic.